# Remove HTML Attributes and tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart2.x

[image]Hi i need to remove HTML attributes and tags using php but `strip_tag` not working give any solutions. Some span attributes come along with the table values. I need to update editable table values in mysql db.  Please find the attached Error Image in console log. I am working opencart ecommerce site. Its different kind of php language.

**View File**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $add; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        <button type="submit" form="form-product" formaction="<?php echo $copy; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_copy; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_delete; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('<?php echo $text_confirm; ?>') ? $('#form-product').submit() : false;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
      </div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($success) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $success; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <?php echo $text_list; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-model"><?php echo $entry_model; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="filter_model" value="<?php echo $filter_model; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_model; ?>" id="input-model" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-price"><?php echo $entry_price; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="filter_price" value="<?php echo $filter_price; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" id="input-price" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_quantity; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="filter_quantity" value="<?php echo $filter_quantity; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_quantity; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
                <select name="filter_status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                  <option value="*"></option>
                  <?php if ($filter_status) { ?>
                  <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if (!$filter_status && !is_null($filter_status)) { ?>
                  <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-image"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></label>
                <select name="filter_image" id="input-image" class="form-control">
                  <option value="*"></option>
                  <?php if ($filter_image) { ?>
                  <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if (!$filter_image && !is_null($filter_image)) { ?>
                  <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="input-date"><?php echo $entry_date; ?></label>
                  <input type="text" name="filter_date" value="<?php echo $filter_date; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date; ?>" id="input-date" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <!--<div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php //echo $entry_quantity; ?></label>
                 <input type="text" name="filter_quantity" value="<?php //echo $filter_quantity; ?>" placeholder="<?php //echo $entry_quantity; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
               </div>-->
            </div>
              <button type="button" id="button-filter" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> <?php echo $button_filter; ?></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form action="<?php echo $delete; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-product">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 1px;" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);" /></td>
                  <td class="text-center"><?php echo $column_image; ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'pd.name') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_name; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_name; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_name; ?>"><?php echo $column_name; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'p.model') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_model; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>"><?php echo $column_model; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'p.seo') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>" class="<?php //echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_seo; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>"><?php echo $column_seo; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td> 
                  <td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'p.date') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>" class="<?php //echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_date; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_model; ?>"><?php echo $column_date; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>     
                  <td class="text-right"><?php if ($sort == 'p.price') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_price; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_price; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_price; ?>"><?php echo $column_price; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                  <td class="text-right"><?php if ($sort == 'p.quantity') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_quantity; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_quantity; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_quantity; ?>"><?php echo $column_quantity; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'p.status') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_status; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo $column_status; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $sort_status; ?>"><?php echo $column_status; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?></td>

                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $column_action; ?></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php if ($products) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <tr id = "<?php $product['product_id'];?>" >
                  <td class="text-center"><?php if (in_array($product['product_id'], $selected)) { ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" />
                    <?php } ?></td>

                  <td class="text-center"><?php if ($product['image']) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="img-thumbnail list"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x"></i></span>
                    <?php } ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['keyword']; ?></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['date_available']; ?></td>

                  <td contenteditable="true" onblur = "update(this, 'price','<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>')" class="text-right"><?php if ($product['special']) { ?>
                    <span style="text-decoration: line-through;"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span><br/>
                    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                    <?php } ?></td>

                  <td contenteditable="true" onblur = "update(this, 'quantity','<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>')" class="text-right"><?php if ($product['quantity'] <= 0) { ?>
                    <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                    <?php } elseif ($product['quantity'] <= 5) { ?>
                    <span class="label label-danger"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="label label-success"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                    <?php } ?></td>

                  <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['status']; ?></td>

                  <td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['edit']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_edit; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

                  <!--<a href="<?php echo $product['inline_update']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php //echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>--></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
    var url = 'index.php?route=catalog/product&token=<?php echo $token; ?>';

    var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').val();

    if (filter_name) {
        url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
    }

    var filter_model = $('input[name=\'filter_model\']').val();

    if (filter_model) {
        url += '&filter_model=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_model);
    }

    var filter_price = $('input[name=\'filter_price\']').val();

    if (filter_price) {
        url += '&filter_price=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_price);
    }

    var filter_quantity = $('input[name=\'filter_quantity\']').val();

    if (filter_quantity) {
        url += '&filter_quantity=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_quantity);
    }

    var filter_status = $('select[name=\'filter_status\']').val();

    if (filter_status != '*') {
        url += '&filter_status=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_status);
    }

   var filter_image = $('select[name=\'filter_image\']').val();

   if (filter_image != '*') {
        url += '&filter_image=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_image);
   }

   var filter_date = $('input[name=\'filter_date\']').val();

   if (filter_date) {
        url += '&filter_date=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_date);
    }

    location = url;
});
//--></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function update(editableObj, column, product_id)
{
    // if(confirm('Are you sure Update this data?'))
    // {
        //console.log(editableObj, column, product_id);
        // return false;
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: "JSON",
            data: "column="+column+"&value="+editableObj.innerHTML+"&product_id="+product_id,
            success: function(data) {
                // set updated value as old value
                $(editableObj).attr('data-old_value',editableObj.innerHTML);
                //$(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                console.log(data);
                },
            // error: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
            // }

        });
    // }    
}
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'filter_name\']').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['product_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').val(item['label']);
    }
});

$('input[name=\'filter_model\']').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_model=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['model'],
                        value: item['product_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'filter_model\']').val(item['label']);
    }
});
//--></script></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

**Controller File.**

```
public function update() 
    {   

        $this->load->language('catalog/product');

        //$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        // print_r(strip_tags($this->request->post['product_id']));
        // print_r($this->request->post['column']);
        // print_r(strip_tags(trim($this->request->post['value'])));
        // die;
        $product_id = strip_tags($this->request->post['product_id']);
        $column = $this->request->post['column'];
        $editableobj = strip_tags(trim($this->request->post['value'])); 
        $this->model_catalog_product->updateProduct($product_id, $column, $editableobj);

    }
```

**Error Report**

```
[52price7897
index.php?route=catalog/product&token=4IEByubsLQVVEvXwKEaL0hytqZose2Wj:1006 52quantity&lt;span class=&quot;label label-warning&quot;&gt;9878970&lt;/span&gt;][1]
```

Comment: whats value of $token ?

Comment: its login session values using opencart only .

Comment: strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')) use this one, in $result['name'] give your varaibale name, it will work, you need to also use html_entity_decode function

Comment: strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')) code is working thanks karthickeyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')) use this one, in $result['name'] give your varaibale name, it will work, you need to also use html_entity_decode function** This code is working thanks karthickeyan